# $33=\left\{a^3+b^3+c^3 \mid (a, b, c) \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, summation, cubics

I was just wondering, if I had an equation like:

$$33 = \left\{a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \mid (a, b, c) \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

What are the values of $(a, b \land c)$. Is there a way of proving or disproving that such integers of $a$, $b$, and $c$ exist to satisfy this equation? Recently the equation:

$$74 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3$$

Was solved, and there proved to be integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ that satisfied this equation. Could you please help for $33$? Thanks :)

UPDATE: I did not realise this was an open question and that we need hefty computers to solve an equation like this, but thank you people for helping me out. I guess if $(a, b \lor c) \to \pm \infty$ then it is only a matter of trial and error before we find a solution. After looking at Numberphile, I realised how this question was not just any "ordinary problem".

Comment: Oh, trite. You must have seen the Numberphile video. Please get a bigger computer.

Comment: They **wouldn't** be positive integers!

Comment: That is still on open problem: https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/integers-equal-to-the-sum-of-three-cubes/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an open problem and is unlikely to be answerable at this point in time.

Comment: @T. Gun Where does it say that open problems are off topic?

Comment: @T.Gunn As written, the problem is simple and can be answered (for strictly positive $a$, $b$, $c$).

Comment: @T.Gunn This is not open problem, since a,b,c is positive integers.

Comment: @above I'm fairly sure that OP meant integers even if they didn't know they meant integers and I'm fairly sure OP knows this is an open problem which they found on Numberphile or something.

Comment: @T.Gunn: yep, this is obvious. Seeing the answers, the OP will understand his mistake.

Comment: @A.W.Grossbard [Real Questions Have Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) If someone posts an open problem asking for what is known about it that's fine. If someone posts an open problem and omits telling people that it is open hoping that somehow, if people don't know it's open, they will suddenly be able to produce an answer for them, that's abusive.

Comment: @T. Gunn Your link has zero to do with unresolved mathematical questions. It is about open ended subjective questions, an idea with absolutely no relationship to open questions in mathematics. I agree that asking open questions here tends not to be productive, but nowhere in the rules does it say you can't.

Comment: @XKCD Ultimately it is the community that decides what is allowable in a question. See [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9977/437127) on meta with 21 upvotes.

Comment: $74 = (−284650292555885)^3 + 66229832190556^3 + 283450105697727^3$ This solution was found in a recent [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07746.pdf).

Comment: [Timothy Browning](https://pub.ist.ac.at/~tbrownin/) found $33=(8866128975287528)^3+(-8778405442862239)^3+(-2736111468807040)^3$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note in your case, the max value of $a,b,c$ is achieved when both others are zero, and hence is $33^{1/3} \approx 3.2$, so since they must be integers, you have $a,b,c \in \{0,1,2,3\}$.

Now it is easy to find all combinations of these in 4 variables. Without loss of generality, assume $a \ge b \ge c$, and you get the following list of combinations (I used Excel but you can enumerate any way you like):

$$
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a & b & c & a^3+b^3+c^3 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 9 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 10 \\
2 & 2 & 0 & 16 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 17 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 24 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 27 \\
3 & 1 & 0 & 28 \\
3 & 1 & 1 & 29 \\
3 & 2 & 0 & 35 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 36 \\
3 & 2 & 2 & 43 \\
3 & 3 & 0 & 54 \\
3 & 3 & 1 & 55 \\
3 & 3 & 2 & 62 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 81 \\
\end{array}
$$

It is clear that no answer results in 33...

**UPDATE**
As @Ture points out in the comments below, doing this for $74$ shows that there are no solutions to $a^3+b^3+c^3=74$ for non-negative $a,b,c$ either. This shows conclusively that you cannot restrict $a,b,c$ thus, and the result OP quotes likely features at least one of $a,b,c$ less than zero.

Comment: The same idea applied to74 yields the same answer... You won't get 74 either.

Comment: @Ture Correct! Which proves conclusively the OP is wrong and that $a,b,c$ cannot be restricted to positive integers!

Comment: The OP excluded $0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you are right, but I did the effort anyway to show that relaxing the positive to non-negative does not help here either

Comment: For this problem and similar ones, it is questionable whether zeroes should be accepted as this changes the nature of the problem: sum of three cubes vs. sum of at most three cubes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it's almost like you think zero isn't a cube. :-)

Comment: @Joffan: I expected this comment but, no, $0$ is tantamount to no variable. Fermat didn't consider $a^n=b^n$.

Comment: So this means that either $a$, $b$, or $c$ must be an integer that is less than $0$. Thanks for helping me out with this one. I will check out Numberphile. I think I gave out the wrong question and that integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ can tend to negative infinity or positive infinity. I will re-edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

The set of possible values is tiny, as $4^3>33$ and $2\cdot 3^3>33$. Assuming $a\le b\le c$, you only have to try with

$$\color{green}{1,1,1}\\1,1,2\\\color{green}{1,1,3}\\\color{green}{1,2,2}\\1,2,3\\2,2,2\\\color{green}{2,2,3}.$$

Note that preliminary computation of the parity (odd) further speeds-up the screening.

Comment: Why.  (2,2,2)(2,2,3)? Possible case are only $ (1,1,1)(1,1,3)(1,2,2)(2,2,3)$ by thinking even or odd.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Oops, fixing.